# How do I catch ng-model databinding errors in AngularJS as a developer?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, error-handling

I am thinking of cases where I mistype something like

```
<input id="firstName" ng-model="vm.firstNameeeee"/>
```

or a case where the *ng-model* is bound correctly, but the model on the server-side changes and now the ng-model isn't correct any more.

As it stands now, Angular just ignores this and does not display anything.

For more data-intensive applications, you would prefer some ability to catch these things and display them to the developer, so these bugs are caught early.

Is there a way to catch such databinding errors in the Angular ng-model? Do you follow a certain practice to catch this early?

Thank you!

Comment: You can decorate the ng-model directive... check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488426/can-you-log-angular-data-binding-errors/23923297

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of catching such errors is at the time of testing.

After completion of a piece of code, I test the code (manually by verifying the functionality in the browser) and then if the functionality is not working, proceed to find the cause of it.

Yes, AngularJS is silent and does not throw errors even in the console. So, the best way to catch these errors is to code in a modular fashion, code small chunks of functionality and at each pitstop, verify if the functionality works.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was hoping there was a better fool-proof way of catching this silly errors. With a big scale enterprise app, it would be real hard to catch all the 'typos' in the view.