# Error message to text files in angular 2/4

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-directives

Is there any possible to write error message into text file or .log extension file using in angular 2/4?? thank you for Advance..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you log angular data-binding errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488426/can-you-log-angular-data-binding-errors)

Comment: No, my question is different ..actually my console errors display on UI using binding now i want to read into text file..Is there any posssible??

Comment: Me also need to do this.can anyone pls help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save the output of a console.log(object) to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file)